# How to use list as stack in Elisp?

Tags: emacs, stack, elisp

I want to use list as stack (or maybe there is stack datatype), to push something (a cons) and then pop it at later time, what is the easiest way to do that in elisp?

I think that `add-to-list` will act like push but what do I use for pop?

Comment: No, `add-to-list` won't quite act like `push`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conveniently there are functions called `push` and `pop` that do exactly that.